# Get a weighted average of a filtered table

Tags: excel, google-sheets, weighted-average

I'm looking for a solution that would give me a weighted average based on a dynamically filtered table. Here is what I have:

Column A: a list of urls, 
Column B: numbers,
Column C: percentages

```
/page                   100000  20%
/brochures.htm?en       27443   75,30%
/brochures.htm?fr       1656    67,33%
/brochures.htm?it       483     75,00%
/brochures.htm?fr-fr    6       0,00%
```

What I want, is a formula that give me the weighted percentage of the pages that start with "/brochures/htm", which is in this case: 74,83%.

I am able to do it in two times with an intermediate sheet where I filter the table with
=FILTER(A1:C5;REGEXMATCH(A1:A5;"/brochures.html*"))
then in the third sheet by calculating the weighted average with
=SUMPRODUCT(C1:C5;B1:B5)/SUM(B1:B5)
, but as you can imagine it is not a good solution for my needs.

Anyone can help?  I've created a google sheet so you can easily understand how I get to that 74,83%.
-> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q-ydRSOdoGN2wVj7Z4XWglz-0U7pL3_xMeyGdRB2K84/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: To make it easier for us to help you, please provide more detail as to your data.  I don't see how you get the results you post from the data you provide.  Please read [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added a google sheet to help you understand @RonRosenfeld ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Excel**. You could use an array formula to achieve this. Make sure to use Ctrl + Shift + Enter instead of just Enter after typing out the formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(LEFT(A1:A5,14)="/brochures.htm",B1:B5,0),C1:C5)/SUM(IF(LEFT(A1:A5,14)="/brochures.htm",B1:B5,0))
```

I tested this with your sample data above in Excel and it came out with 74.83%. I hope this helps

For **Google sheets** this will work:
`=ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT(IF(LEFT(A1:A5,14)="/brochures.htm",B1:B5,0),C1:C5)/SUM(IF(LEFT(A1:A5,14)="/brochures.htm",B1:B5,0)))`

or use semicolon `;` instead the coma `,` if your local setting are different from the US.

Comment: I just tried that, but I get an error. What do you mean by "use ctrl + shift + enter": when should I use that shortcut and what does it do? @maxhob17

Comment: In Excel, instead of just Enter after typing your formula, use Ctrl + Shift + Enter, this creates an array formula as opposed to a regular one http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/array-formulas.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this formula would help (Google Sheets only):

`=QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({A3:C8};"select 'avg', Col2*Col3, Col2 where Col1 like '/brochures.htm%'");"select Col1, sum(Col2)/sum(Col3) group by Col1");"select Col2 Label Col2 ''")`

**First query** selects `Col2*Col3, Col2` when conditions are met: `Col1 like '/brochures.htm%'`

**Second query**
finds the weighted average of a filtered table

**Third query**
gets only the resulting number from the second query

In your sample:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q-ydRSOdoGN2wVj7Z4XWglz-0U7pL3_xMeyGdRB2K84/edit#gid=1380706652

---

The benefit of using this formula is that you have to reference the data only once, and also you have more [setting tools with query](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) formula.